# Image size become too small after compression

Tags: android, image, file-upload, android-volley

I am trying to send image to server by converting to Base64 string, but after compression image becomes too small at server side.

[image: Image become too small]

***Code:***

```
public String getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
    // get the base 64 string
    String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return imgString;
}
```

Serverside Code :

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult UploadFile()
    {
        string filePath = "No File Uploaded"; 
        HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var fileData = httpRequest.Form["fileData"];
        try
        {
            string lUniqueId = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmssff");
            string lFileName = lUniqueId + ".jpeg";
            filePath = "~/Uploads/AadharCards/" + lFileName;

            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(fileData);
            //Save the Byte Array as File.
            File.WriteAllBytes(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(filePath), imageBytes);
            return Ok(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Ok(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to decode your image after encoding it? Maybe it's a server issue as your code seems correct?

Comment: `trying to send image to server by converting to Base64 string, but after compression image becomes too small at server side.` Please tell resolution of original image. Then resolution of resized image on the client. Then resolution of image on sever.

Comment: `Image size become too small after compression` I think your bitmap is already too small before compression. Please tell bmp.getWidth() and bmp.getHeight(). Where did you get that bitmap from to begin with?

Comment: original image 2448 x 3264        server image 427 x 60

Comment: I asked for three resolutions.

Comment: And what do you mean with 'compression'? bitmap.compress() or say compress (resize) from 2448x3264 to 150x124 ?

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet seems really good. This can convert image to base64.

I think you can have 3 possible problem.

1. Wrapping problem while converting (You tried)

> Use `Base64.NO_WRAP` instead of `Base64.DEFAULT`

2. Your server code can has a problem while converting base64 to image.

> You can control or share your server side code.

3. While function is working, your bitmap is already too small.

Comment: still image is too small.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code. i have implemented the same functionality. I am getting the image from Gallery and convert the path in byte array. Pass the imagepath to your server.
selectedImage is the URI path of Gallery.

```
    public static byte[] bitmapdata;
    private static String imagepath;


 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImage.toString());
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                    bitmapdata = resizeImage(stream.toByteArray());

                    imagepath = Base64.encodeToString(bitmapdata, Base64.DEFAULT);

/* Resize Image */
        byte[] resizeImage(byte[] input) {
            Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(input, 0, input.length);
            Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(original, 400, 480, true);

            ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, blob);

            return blob.toByteArray();
        }
```

Comment: how to save this image in original size?

Comment: To save the image, you have to do a code at server side and they create the imageurl. Use the imageurl to download from server using Picaso or  glide library.

Comment: No no I mean you've mentioned 400,480 size.I want to save original image.

Comment: Remove the below line from resizeImage method and pass the bitmap object of original instead of resized in compress method.

  Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(original, 400, 480, true);

Comment: but that's the actual problem the image which I want to upload become too small

Comment: you can use it it can not compress using converting byte[]. Something will wrong from your server side.